# how to match data in rows from one data frame to the column names in another data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 data frames. One is the details of all calls for service in 2021 and I named it data_1. And the second is a code file that will allow you to convert coded fields into normal descriptions and I named it code_file. The code_file looks something like this

| id | codevalue | descr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc.1 | 021 | Action taken |
| abc.2 | 078 | search and rescue |
| inc.type | 7845 | transport |

The data_1 df with details for all calls looks something like this

| state | inc.type | abc.1 | abc.2 | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FL | 321 | 33 | 44 | ORL |
| FL | 781 | 59 | 317 | MIAMI |
| FL | 777 | 0154 | 441 | MIAMI |

How do I merge the two data frames in a way that the values in column "id" from code_file match with the column names in data_1?

| state | inc.type | abc.1 | abc.2 | city | codevalue | descr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FL | 321 | 33 | 44 | ORL | 021 | Action taken |
| FL | 781 | 59 | 317 | MIAMI | 078 | search and rescue |
| FL | 777 | 0154 | 441 | MIAMI | 7845 | transport |

The output should look something like this

I don't have any code for this right now as I am struggling.

Comment: What's your criteria for matching? it seems that you randomly did a `bind_cols`! Explain in details why each row of `data_1` matched with the one of `code_file`.

Comment: Something like this would've made sense to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMvvy.png

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
 mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
 pivot_longer(cols = all_of(df1$id), names_to = 'id') %>% 
 left_join(df1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'id', values_from = value)%>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  fill(all_of(df1$id), .direction = "downup") %>% 
  slice(cur_group_id()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(any_of(union(names(df2), names(df1)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
  state inc.type abc.1 abc.2 city  codevalue descr            
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <chr>     <int> <chr>            
1 FL         321    33    44 ORL          21 Action taken     
2 FL         781    59   317 MIAMI        78 search and rescue
3 FL         777   154   441 MIAMI      7845 transport
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("abc.1", "abc.2", "inc.type"), codevalue = c(21L, 
78L, 7845L), descr = c("Action taken", "search and rescue", "transport"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(state = c("FL", "FL", "FL"), inc.type = c(321L, 
781L, 777L), abc.1 = c(33L, 59L, 154L), abc.2 = c(44L, 317L, 
441L), city = c("ORL", "MIAMI", "MIAMI")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I tried this but I am getting this error Error in `bind_cols()`:
! Can't recycle `..1` (size 121075) to match `..2` (size 968).
Backtrace:
 1. df2%>% bind_cols(df1%>% select(fieldid))
 2. dplyr::bind_cols(., df1%>% select(fieldid))

Comment: @akrun I am not sure if I understand what OP means by "match". There's no criteria that would exclude the first row of `data_1` to match with any of the rows from `code_file`. I am leaning towards closing this as Unclear.